# re-fire trigger in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I set an **onEdit** trigger and I wish **re-fire or recall that** in another function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var chng= e.range;

  ///something set a validation on near cell. showing drip list validation..
}

function tst(){
 /// I put a new item in that validated cell
//then the cell warns me with red triangle saying 'invalid content'

// And i run this function to add that new value to validation list range 
// adding works fine. but the red triangle still there 
//and also validation drop list doesn't show that added item.

//so I want to re-fire or refresh onEdit trigger in this function
//to reset validation and erase that warning.

// so something like this..?
var atv = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
onEdit.range = atv;  

////no error occurred on sheet 
////but cell warning and validation didn't change.
}
```

I've try to also pull out functions in onEdit to recall validating functions later. but now onEdit doesn't work.

I've changed trigger target cells value 0 and back to trig again
and added some sleep time from script api.. but it didn't work

So.. is there any idea?

Comment: Just call `onEdit()` in `tst()`? You can construct the event object manuallly using just the parts you need.

Comment: @Robin Gertenbach // yes it in the last tst() (onEdit.range = atv;)and found some onEdit methods from google api ref but its not that specific..

Comment: Maybe elaborate a bit more. To me it sounds like you just want to trigger onEdit again, which you can do with `onEdit` If your `onEdit` is using the event object you can pass an object containing the parameters along with it.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
var e = {'range' : 'defined onEdit Range'};
onEdit(e);
```

newbb always find answer just tip of nose tip..;-/

ps. thanks Robin Gertenbach